# Break up a tuple unpacking where the list of names breaks the character limit

Tags: python, pep8

I have a function which returns a long tuple.  I want to unpack the result, but writing out a list of names breaks the PEP 8 character limit.  How can I reformat the code so that it doesn't exceed the character limit?

```
def x():
    return 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

xaaa1, xaaa2, xaaa3, xaaa4, xaaa5, xaaa6 = x()
```

<sup><sub>Assume the example is representative of a longer line of code.</sub></sup>

Comment: Use a pep8 linter and see what happens.

Comment: What is "way too long" about that?

Comment: I don't think there is anything un-pep8 or or inherently unpythonic about `xaaa1,xaaa2,xaaa3,xaaa4,xaaa5,xaaa6 = x()`. I you are using Python 3 and there is some kind of grouping, you can do something like `first,  *middle, last = x()`. Experiment with putting the star before `first` and `last` as well.

Comment: the variable names xaaa1 are just examples, the real variable names are very long and this that spans multiple lines. I will accept the answer with adding () in left side too, as I do not want to change these variable elsewhere in the code.